# Are files in Virtualbox safe from external attacker?

Tags: virtualbox, security

I need to use a potentially unsafe computer to handle sensitive information. I was thinking of using a Virtualbox with an encrypted Linux installation to put the file inside. Is there still a way a (potential) attacker (with full access to the host) can have access to the data? He could of course destroy it (along with the entire virtual machine), but that doesn't bother me. What I don't want is anyone being able to read it.

Comment: There are indeed attacks that exists, that make it possible for malware to escape a virtual machine, but asking if its "possible" is way too broad of a question.

Comment: I don't get why it is broad. The question is a yes/no question: "Is a file in a virtualbox with a potentially compromised host safe?"

Comment: The reason it is broad (IMO) is because its not simply a "Yes" or "No" answer.  Even if it was "Yes and "No" questions are normally horrible questions.  In reality the answer entirely depends on what the host OS is compromised with specifically, what virtualization extensions your system is using, and lots of other factors not worth listing in a comment.  You don't have to agree with my opinion, that asking if its possible for a compromised host to access information on a guest virtual machine is too broad of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that situation is not safe.  Virtualization protects guest machines from accessing resources on the host, however if the host is compromised an attacker would have access to the entire host system as well as any guests running on the host.  You need to put your unsafe machine into a VM.